# Components of speed vector after bouncing of a tilted wall

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, collision

[image]

Suppose a ball with velocity $v$ hits a 45 degree tilted wall at an angle $\theta$. Let $v_x$ and $v_y$ be the components of $v$ before the hit, what are the components after the hit as a function of $v_x$ and $v_y$? Can this be generalized to a tilted wall of any angle? Assume elastic collision and no gravity.

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: this answer is such that theta is the angle between the wall and the initial trajectory. not the standard angle of incidence measured from the normal

Using geometry, we can say that the velocity vector has to be rotated $2\theta$ clockwise

thus using a rotation matrix we can say the transformation from incidence  to reflection is

$$\begin{pmatrix}cos(2\theta) & sin(2\theta)\\\ -sin(2\theta) & cos(2\theta)\end{pmatrix}$$

The left column Is the coordinate of basis vector I, and the right column is the coordinate of the j basis vector. The reflected beam should be

$$Vx \begin{bmatrix} cos(2\theta) \cr -sin(2\theta) \end{bmatrix} + Vy\begin{bmatrix} sin(2\theta) \cr cos(2\theta)\end{bmatrix}$$